# PHP Include for file in same directory

Tags: php

I hope someone will spot my error because this has been killing me. I am trying to include a file that contains some variables into my includes file and then echo those variables in another file in the same folder.

My vars.php file:

```
<?php
$telephone = "+27 32 815 0400";
?>
```

My includes.php file:

```
<?php
include_once('vars.php');
//Some other code//
?>
```

My header.php file:

```
<?php
include_once('includes.php');
echo $telephone;
?>
```

I know there are probably some bad practices here as I'm pretty new to PHP, please just ignore them unless they're actually causing the issue.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't get what you actually meant

Comment: You missed `include('includes.php');` in your file **header.php**.

Comment: Are all the files in the same directory?

Comment: Thanks @Zeratops, Rookie Error!

Comment: May I ask if it solved your issue @Stiaanvm ?